# Nesting tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs, tikz-node, tikz-feynman

I want to put a tikz graph (a Feynman diagram using `tikz-feynman`) inside other tikz nodes, but it doesn't seem to work.  A MWE is below.  It has to be compiled with `lualatex` as I'm using graphs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  box/.pic={
    \feynmandiagram[inner,horizontal=a to d]{
      a -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] c -- [fermion] d -- [draw=none]
      e -- [fermion] f -- [fermion] g -- [fermion] h -- [draw=none] a,
      b -- [boson] g, c -- [boson] f,
    };
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [clockwise=4,radius=5em]{
    % a/{B}, b/{\tikz{\pic {box};}}, c/{C}, d/{f}  %% <-- what I want to do
    a/{B}, b/{box}, c/{C}, d/{f}
  };
  \graph {
    (a) -> {(b), (d)}, {(b), (d)} -> (c)
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

*PS:* I also found out `tikz-feynman` does not work with the `standalone` document class after I had wasted a few hours!

*EDIT*: Thanks to @TorbjørnT., the above issues is due to `standalone`, and is resolved by starting with `\RequirePackage{luatex85}`.

Comment: `tikz-feynman` works fine with `standalone`, but  `standalone` doesn't work with `lualatex`. To fix that, add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` just before `\documentclass{standalone}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks a lot! I'll try it out in the morning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nesting `tikzpicture`s isn't something you can always count on working, and you're nesting three levels deep. `\feynmandiagram` starts a `tikzpicture`, `\tikz` is a shortform of `\begin{tikzpicture} .. \end{tikzpicture}`, and you're placing the first inside the second inside a third `tikzpicture`.

An alternative that does work is to use a `savebox`.

Note that you don't actually need `\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}` as `tikz-feynman` loads both.

[image: output of code]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\newsavebox{\foo}
\savebox{\foo}{
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to d]{
      a -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] c -- [fermion] d -- [draw=none]
      e -- [fermion] f -- [fermion] g -- [fermion] h -- [draw=none] a,
      b -- [boson] g, c -- [boson] f,
    };}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [clockwise=4,radius=10em]{
     a/{B}, b/\usebox{\foo}, c/{C}, d/{f} 
  };
  \graph {
    (a) -> {(b), (d)}, {(b), (d)} -> (c)
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) ... and should count on never working :-)

Comment: This works very well.  I wanted to avoid nesting in the first place, but didn't know how to go about it.  Thank you!